# Hyperledger Fabric - Cannot invoke a transaction - Endorsement has failed

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

My company have a blockchain network used fabric image version 1.4.0 which deployed on Portainer
And I have installed and instantiated my chaincode (javascript) on that blockchain network.

I have created an application (typescript) to interract with this chaincode. But it seem that only evaluationTransaction (query) is call successfully. I have tried to perform a submitTransaction (invoke) but it always return an error:

```
2021-03-11T09:48:43.964Z - warn: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _build_endorse_group_member >> G2:0 - endorsement failed - Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses
2021-03-11T09:48:43.967Z - error: [DiscoveryEndorsementHandler]: _endorse - endorsement failed::Error: Endorsement has failed
```

When I check log in dev-peer0.xxx.xxx.xx container, it show that the query (evaluationTransaction) commands always reach this peer, but invoke (submitTransaction) not have any logs.

Here is the dev-peer0.xxx.xxx.xx log:

[image]

Here is my network-config.json:

```
  "name": "connection",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "client": {
    "organization": "MyOrg",
    "connection": {
      "timeout": {
        "peer": {
          "endorser": "300"
        },
        "orderer": "300"
      }
    }
  },
  "channels": {
    "channelorg": {
      "orderers": [
        "orderer0.myorg.com",
        "orderer1.myorg.com"
      ],
      "peers": {
        "peer0.myorg.com": {},
        "peer1.myorg.com": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "organizations": {
    "MyOrg": {
      "mspid": "MyOrg",
      "peers": [
        "peer0.myorg.com",
        "peer1.myorg.com"
      ],
      "certificateAuthorities": [
        "ca.myorg.com"
      ]
    }
  },
  "orderers": {
    "orderer0.myorg.com": {
      "url": "grpcs://10.10.10.1:7050",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer0.myorg.com",
        "hostnameOverride": "orderer0.myorg.com"
      },
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "src/blockchain-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/myorg.com/orderers/orderer0.myorg.com/tls/ca.crt"
      }
    },
    "orderer1.myorg.com": {
      "url": "grpcs://10.10.10.2:7050",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer1.myorg.com",
        "hostnameOverride": "orderer1.myorg.com"
      },
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "src/blockchain-network/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/myorg.com/orderers/orderer1.myorg.com/tls/ca.crt"
      }
    }
  },
  "peers": {
    "peer0.myorg.com": {
      "url": "grpcs://10.10.10.3:7051",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.myorg.com",
        "hostnameOverride": "peer0.myorg.com"
      },
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "src/blockchain-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/myorg.com/peers/peer0.myorg.com/tls/ca.crt"
      }
    },
    "peer1.myorg.com": {
      "url": "grpcs://10.10.10.4:7051",
      "grpcOptions": {
        "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.myorg.com",
        "hostnameOverride": "peer1.myorg.com"
      },
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "src/blockchain-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/myorg.com/peers/peer1.myorg.com/tls/ca.crt"
      }
    }
  },
  "certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.myorg.com": {
      "url": "https://10.10.10.5:7054",
      "caName": "ca.myorg.com",
      "httpOptions": {
        "verify": false
      },
      "tlsCACerts": {
        "path": "src/blockchain-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/myorg.com/ca/ca.myorg.com-cert.pem"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please advise me to fix it.
Thanks so much.

**Updated:**

When I make a submitTransaction, it will occur an error below.

[image]

So I have changed "*discovery: {enabled} option*" from true to false in *gateway.connect()* arguments and the submitTransaction has been sent successfully.

[image]

Thanks very much.

Comment: I am glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the private key of the organization is missing here in the connection profile. I have attached the connection-profile. Please copy the admin keys from the blockchain-network crypto-config directory into your connection profile.
In the organization description,the ***adminPrivateKey and signedCert*** is missing in your connection configuration.

```
name: "Network"
version: "1.0"

channels:
  mychannel:
    orderers:
      - orderer.example.com
    peers:
      peer0.org1.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true
      peer0.org2.example.com:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: false
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: false

organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: Org1MSP
    peers:
      - peer0.org1.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca-org1
adminPrivateKey:
  path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/keystore/9022d671ceedbb24af3ea69b5a8136cc64203df6b9920e26f48123fcfcb1d2e9_sk
signedCert:
  path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem

  Org2:
    mspid: Org2MSP
    peers:
      - peer0.org2.example.com
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca-org2
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/keystore/5a983ddcbefe52a7f9b8ee5b85a590c3e3a43c4ccd70c7795bec504e7f74848d_sk
    signedCert:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/signcerts/Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem

orderers:
  orderer.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7050
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer.example.com
      grpc-max-send-message-length: 4194304
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tlscacerts/example.com-cert.pem

peers:
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:7051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org1.example.com
      grpc.keepalive_time_ms: 600000
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tlscacerts/org1.example.com-cert.pem

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    url: grpcs://localhost:8051
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer0.org2.example.com
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tlscacerts/org2.example.com-cert.pem

certificateAuthorities:
  ca-org1:
    url: https://localhost:7054
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/org1.example.com-cert.pem
    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: caorg1

  ca-org2:
    url: https://localhost:8054
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: test/fixtures/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/org2.example.com-cert.pem
    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: caorg2
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have tried to add adminPrivateKey and signedCert to the connection configuration json file but this problem still exist.